# Passing NSMutableArray to the server

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, post, nsstring, nsarray

I'm currently working with AddressBook in iOS, I'm getting the emails from all the contacts of the user, and putting them into the `NSMutableArray`. Now I must to pass this array to the server[PHP]. But the problem that is the emails are in the double quotes, so it looks something like this:

```
(
  "user@gmail.com",
  "user2@gmail.com",
  "user3@gmail.com"
)
```

That is my code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        accessGranted = granted;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
    accessGranted = YES;
}

if (accessGranted) {
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    _usersEmails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:CFArrayGetCount(people)];
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++) {
            NSData* email = [(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [_usersEmails addObject:email];
        }
        CFRelease(emails);
    }
    CFRelease(addressBook);
    CFRelease(people);
```

Web-programmer that was implementing the server-side, told me that I must to pass the array of strings without the double quotes.

**How can I remove the double quotes in each string of my array?**

Update:

This is the piece of the actual data that had been received by the server:

```
\"user@gmail.com\"','\"user@gmail.com\"','\"user@gmail.com\"','\"user@me.com\"
```

Comment: Both you and your web-programmer should look into JSON.

Comment: @Martol1ni what do you mean, I'm getting response in JSON format, I tried to use JSONRepresentation but still there is double quotes in each string.

Comment: @AnatoliyGatt, Strings are represented with double quotes in JSON. Probably your web programmer need to fix something on his side. This looks fine for me. http://json.org/example.html

Comment: @Martol1ni Maybe it is one thing, but I'm printing array into the console, and there is a double quotes, but the strings itself doesn't havr any queotes, I think, that the NSArray puts them for me.

Comment: Printing to the console isn't the same if you're just using NSLog to log the array itself. The description of an object isn't necessarily its "string" representation.

Comment: @AnatoliyGatt, Yes, while printing it shows with double quotes. That is the way strings are represented in console when you add them to arrays and dictionaries. That doesn't mean that double quotes are added to those strings.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the values are in double quotes.  That's just the way that NSArray.description displays character strings containing blanks or "odd" characters.

Comment: Please look on the update, I post the actual data that was received by the server

Comment: Can you post your conversion to JSON code? The problem may lie there.

Comment: NSArray ***does not*** add quotes to strings.  We've got probably 20 years of experience with it between us, and no one has ever seen this.  My suspicion is that the process used to convert the NSArray to your transmitted data is at fault.

Comment: Note that if you do something like `NSString* xmitData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _userEmails);` you'll generate a string containing quotes.  This is because you're implicitly using NSArray.description, which is intended only for diagnostic displays.

Comment: (I gather from your silence that you've finally seen the error of your ways.)

Comment: @HotLicks The web programmer just fixed something on the server side.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NSString's `substringFromIndex` and `substringToIndex` methods to eliminate the first and last characters. Something like `[[string substringToIndex:string.length - 1] substringFromIndex:1];`

EDIT:

And can't you check/remove the quotation marks here:

```
NSData* email = [(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j) dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

by writing something like:

```
NSString *string = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);
NSString *stringWithoutQuotations = [[string substringToIndex:string.length - 1] substringFromIndex:1];
NSData* email = [stringWithoutQuotations  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have quotes in my strings, but when I put the strings into the array, NSArray puts the strigns into double quotes, and separate elements by comma(that is fine), is there any way to convert it to soem specific representation, that is good for sending to the server?

Comment: Please look on the update, I post the actual data that was received by the server!

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are shown when NSString is printed to the console--I don't think your strings actually contain quotation marks..

Try using the debugger inspector instead to double-check.

Comment: Please look on the update, I post the actual data that was received by the server!

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
for (NSString* aString in _userEmails) {
    NSLog(@"The string is %@", aString);
}
```

You will see that there are no quotes.

Comment: Please look on the update, I post the actual data that was received by the server!

Comment: @AnatoliyGatt - How did you generate that string for the server??